# not getting the form values from login form

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, authentication

here is my code . i am not able to get the form data via php. even i echoed the form data but it is showing nothinh only reloading the login page
login form

```
<form id="loginform" action="sql.php" method="post">
    <label style="text-align:center" for="Email">Email &nbsp; &nbsp;:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php               echo         $user_profile['email'];?>">
    <label for="pass" style="text-align:center;">Password &nbsp;:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <div id="space" style="height:15px; width:500px; margin:auto;"></div>
    <div id="button" style="height:30px; width:50px; margin:auto;">
    <input type="submit"onclick="return verify(this);"name="submit" value="LoG In"        style="border:outset; border-color:#000080; margin:auto;">
    </div>
</form>
```

and 
        sql.php file

```php
 <?php
   $a = $_POST['email'];
   $b = $_POST['password'];
   $c = mysql_real_escape_string($a);
   $d = mysql_real_escape_string($b);
   $e = htmlentities($c);
    $f = htmlentities($d);
    $user = strip_tags($e);
    $pass = strip_tags($f);
    session_start();
    $dbhost = '';
    $dbuser = '';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = '';
    $table  = '';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die ("I cannot connect to          the        database because: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("I cannot select the database because: "           .mysql_error());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO data (email, password) VALUES('$user','$pass')";
    $result = mysql_query($conn,$sql);
    if($result){
echo $user;
echo  "";
echo $pass;};
     mysql_close($conn);?>
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Right off the bat, try putting your `session_start();` at the top and under `<?php`. Will see what else I can find.

Comment: You have `$user_profile['email'];`. `email` is the name set for the variable `$user_profile`, but then you assign `$a` to `email`. That, I don't get. Should probably be `$user_profile = $_POST['email'];` and so on and so forth. `$user_profile` is getting `lost in the shuffle`, as it were.

Comment: That's one funny login form; inserting the posted data into the table instead of comparing it to existing values...

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is completely wrong, you are doing a database insert instead of comparing the posted values against existing values in the table.

However, your current problem is caused by your use of `mysql_real_escape_string`. As you use that function before you open a database connection, it will return `FALSE`, effectively emptying your variables before you even try to use them.

You should switch to PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements because the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Then you need to `SELECT` a row from the database, based on the posted information instead of inserting one.

If you cannot / do not want to switch to PDO or mysqli, you should open your database connection before you use `mysql_real_escape_string`, so you could change your code to:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die ("I cannot connect to the        database because: " . mysql_error());
$a = $_POST['email'];
$b = $_POST['password'];
$c = mysql_real_escape_string($a);
$d = mysql_real_escape_string($b);
// etc.
```